# csv.reader without open() function

Tags: python, csv

I want to read a CSV file without using the `open()` function.

```py
file.txt
'xxr'|'wer'|'xxr'|'xxr'
'xxt'|'dse'|'xxt'|'xxt'
'xxv'|'cad'|'xxv'|'xxv'
'xxe'|'sdf'|'xxe'|'xxe'
'xxw'|'sder'|'xxw'|'xxw'
'xxz'|'csd'| 'xxz'| 'xxz'
```

I've tried this, but this doesn't open a file. Just use 'file.txt' as a string.

```py
file = ('file.txt')
reader = csv.reader(file,delimiter="|")
mylist = list(reader)
```

I *cannot* use the regular `with open('file.txt', 'r')` ....

Reason: The customer is sending this data pipeline to a platform that doesn't support the open() function, due to directory function restrictions (not a permissions issue).

I also cannot read as Dataframe, because they are unstructured lists, and this template is much simpler.

This is a conversion from a python script to Data Dream, with spark. Kind of odd... but they can reproduce pandas and numpy. They can't use Function `open()` and `with`.

Any ideas?

Comment: *How* is the customer sending the data, if not a file?  `csv.reader` can take a file-like object, such as `io.StringIO` if you just have a data stream.  Edit your question with a [mcve] showing how you access the data.  `file.txt` implies a file, and `open` is how you read a file.  What is your input method?

Comment: This is a conversion from a python script to Data Dream, with spark. Kind of odd... but they can reproduce pandas and numpy. Function open()  and with they can't...

Comment: Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69702202/edit) the appropriate information to the question ([this is not forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115))? Comments may be deleted at any time. (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) although I'm unsure of how the module deals with opening the files and if it is any different than the `open` function but it does allow for multiple files to be opened in order using one stream and it seems to allow for more flexibility in how the file is read:

```
import fileinput

with fileinput.input('file.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(file,delimiter="|")
    mylist = list(reader)
```

Comment: Ok. this is an alternative approach. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(file),delimiter="|")
```

Or with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
mylist = pd.read_csv(file, sep="|").to_numpy().tolist()
```